# Problems figuring out minesweeper code

Tags: java, oop, arrays

I'm trying to populate a 2-dimensional `array` with values (numbers) that correlate to the number of mines adjacent to it.

My thought process would be to compare each cell to the adjacent cell, but I receive an out of bounds exception.

I have been trying a few different ways and I can't seem to get down the logic. I feel like arrays throw me off.

#### Gameboard (class)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoard
{
    private int[][]  mines;
    private char[][] tileCount;
    private int[][]  sol;
    private int Row, Column, mine; 

    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public GameBoard(int Row, int Column, int mine)
    {
        this.Row = Row;
        this.Column = Column;
        this.mine = mine;
        mines = new int[Row][Column];
        tileCount = new char[Row][Column];        
        startMines();
        randomMines();
        fillTips();
        startBoard();
    }

    public void startMines()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < mines.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < mines[0].length; j++)
            {
                mines[i][j] = 0;
            }    
        }
    }

    public void randomMines()
    {

        double x = (Row * Column) * .25;
        int tempRow, tempColumn;
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0 ; j < this.mine ; i++)
        { 
            tempRow = (int)(Math.random() * Row);
            tempColumn = (int)(Math.random() * Column);

            if(mines[tempRow][tempColumn] == 0)
            {
                mines[tempRow][tempColumn] =  9;
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showMines()
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i < Row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j < Column ; j++)
            {
                if ( mines[i][j] == '*')
                {
                    System.out.print(tileCount[i][j]='*');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void fillTips()
    {
        for(int line=0 ; line < Row ; line++)
        {
            for(int column=0 ; column < Column ; column++)
            {
                for(int i=-1 ; i<=0 ; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=-1 ; j<=0 ; j++)
                    {
                        if(mines[line][column] != -1)
                        {
                            if(mines[line][column] == -1)
                            {
                                mines[line][column]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    public void startBoard()
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<mines.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<mines.length ; j++)
            {
                tileCount[i][j]= '.';
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {        
        System.out.println("\n     Lines");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < Row ; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("       "+ (i+1) + " ");
        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j < Column ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print( "   "+ mines[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println();         
        return "\n  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8\n Columns";
    }
}
```

#### GameClient (class)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GameClient 
{
    int grid;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game minesweeper, I hope you enjoy your stay.");
        System.out.println("We will begin by asking how large you would like the game.");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Input two values please: ");
        Scanner grid = new Scanner(System.in);
        int grid1 = grid.nextInt();
        int grid2 = grid.nextInt(); 
        double mineCount = ((grid1*grid2)*.25);
        System.out.println("Enter a number of mines, please 25% less than the total tiles which is " + mineCount);
        Scanner mineCounts = new Scanner(System.in);
        mineCount = mineCounts.nextInt();
        GameBoard[][] tileSize = new GameBoard[grid1][grid2];
        tileSize[0][0] = new GameBoard(grid1, grid2, (int)mineCount);
    


        System.out.println(tileSize[0][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm updating your question.. please review it and consider reposting it at stackoverflow.. in the future, if your program raises an exception, it is likely a stackoverflow question.. think of stackoverflow as the `try catch` of the Q&A community answering world..

Comment: in brief, as food for thought...  a two-dimensional, primitive type `array` (i,e,  `int mines[x][y]`) should be initialized to full capacity, (i.e. `int mines[][] = new int[maxColumn][maxRow]`, remember that columns are counted left to right, or the x axis, and rows are counted top to bottom, or the y axis). `for(int i=0; i < this.maxColumn; i++)` and `for(int j=0; j < this.maxRow; j++)` ... also, your check ` if (mines[i][j] == "*") ` in `showMines` seems improper..

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems in the code.

First in `randomMines` in these lines

```
tempRow = (int)(Math.random() * Row);
tempColumn = (int)(Math.random() * Column);
```

`Math.random()` may return 1.0, so `tempRow` will be equals to `Row` which is the problem because last index is `Row - 1` (and `Column - 1`). So make it like

```
tempRow = (int)(Math.random() * (Row - 1));
tempColumn = (int)(Math.random() * (Column - 1));
```

Another problem is in `startBoard` in the loop

```
for(int i=0 ; i<mines.length ; i++) {
    for(int j=0 ; j<mines.length ; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

you have `mines[0].length` columns as you wrote it in `startMines` method.

And the last error that I saw is in `toString` method. It does not even compile. It should look like this

```
public String toString()
{
    System.out.println("\n     Lines");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < Row ; i++) {
        System.out.print("       " + (i + 1) + " ");
        for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++) {
            System.out.print("   " + mines[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return "\n  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8\n Columns";
}
```

But that does not do what it should, you print values instead of convert them to `String`. It would be better to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\n     Lines\n");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < Row ; i++) {
        builder.append("       " + (i + 1) + " ");
        for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++) {
            builder.append("   " + mines[i][j]);
        }
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    builder.append("\n  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8\n Columns");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Also you can use [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to pretty print your board.